# Multiple Private Chat channels in Pubnub Android

Tags: android, chat, real-time, publish-subscribe, pubnub

Hi I am in the process of making a chat app using pubnub and need some guidance. I have gone through all the tutorials and understood concepts of publish/ subscribe/ multi-indexing/ sending push notifications/ presence API using the android SDK and have made sample public chat app.

Think of my app as a customer care service. I will have multiple users on one end who can choose to initiate a conversation with our employees on the other end. Customers can only chat with our employees(not among each other) and only customers can initiate conversations. How do i go about structuring this?

I had thought of defining every possible channel (upon every signup) between employees and customer using their tokens(or some UUID) in combination as channel names, cust1_empl1, cust1_empl2. Say i have 5 employee, then the channels each customer has will be 5 but for our side, we will need as many channels as there are users which isnt practical.(say 3000 users / employee based on my estimates)

If user 1 talks with employee1

1) Do I have to define cust1_empl1 from first and have both of them publish and subscribe to the channel?

2) Is there a way to make these on the fly? When cust1 starts the chat, I can always create a channel and publish, subscribe to it, but how does the executive at the other end know this user wants to chat and has created a new channel as he has to be prompted to join the channel if it was made on the fly.

3) Do I have to use some sort of public channel to send information between devices as well to notify them of channels being made on the fly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varun,

You can start off by having the customers and your agents subscribe to their personal channel (eg `channel-customer1`). In addition to that, the agents can subscribe to a global channel (eg. `available_agents`) if they are available for a conversation.

As a user, when I want to initiate a chat with an agent, I will publish a message on the global channel

```
PUBNUB.publish({
    channel: 'available_agents',
    message: {"customerID":"customer1", "personalChannel": "channel-customer1"}
});
```

All available agents who are subscribed to that channel will receive this request and can respond to me on my "personal" channel which is identified in the message. To close the loop, I can send another message on the `available-agents` channel to announce that I have successfully started a conversation with an agent. When the pairing between the customer and the agent is done, you can either create a dynamic channel for them to chat on "`customer1-agent1-chat`" or just have both parties publish on each other's personal channel. For example,

- When I want to send a message to the agent, I publish on `channel-agent1`
- When the agent wants to send me a message, he publishes on `channel-customer1`

So to answer your questions:

1. You don't have to "create" the cust1_empl1 channel from the beginning. You only do it when you pair up  the customer and employee.
2. You do this by sending announcing your request for a conversation on a global channel that all available agents are subscribed to. You will also let them know which channel they can reach you on to start the chat.
3. If you are using your server as a middle man to create the dynamic channels, you server can just publish on the customer's and employee's private channel let them know that they have to subscribe to an additional channel for the new conversation

Other things to consider:

1. I would recommend taking a look at [PubNub Access Manager](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pam-security) for security reasons. For example, you can lock down the `available-agents` channel by providing only write access to customers and read access to employees (agents).
2. Another way to manage dynamically created channels and having a customer or employee subscribe to it would be to use [Channel Groups](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-controller#channel_groups). With channel groups, you can have every user just subscribe to a personal channel group. You can manage the subscriptions to individual channels by adding/removing individual channels to a channel group.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sadly my rep isnt high enough for the +1 vote to show :D

Comment: Varun - you'll get there. Gave you a little boost with up vote on your question, because it is a good question :)

Comment: @Girish, Hi, How the channel is created for a one to one chat?